# Quarkus websockets does not seem to be async or just slow?

Tags: java, websocket, netty, vert.x, quarkus

I have this Websocket server code that I am having some performance issue:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/video/{username}")
@ApplicationScoped
public class VideoSocket {

    Map<String, Session> sessions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, @PathParam("username") String username) {
         sessions.put(username, session);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, @PathParam("username") String username) {
         sessions.remove(username);
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session, @PathParam("username") String username, Throwable throwable) {
         sessions.remove(username);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(ByteBuffer message, @PathParam("username") String username) {
        try {
            broadcast(message, username);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void broadcast(ByteBuffer message, String username) {
        sessions.forEach((u,s)->{
                Date start = new Date();
                s.getAsyncRemote().sendObject(message, result ->  {
                    Date finish = new Date();
                    System.out.println("Total send time: " + (finish.getTime() - start.getTime() + " milliseconds."));
                    if (result.getException() != null) {
                        System.out.println("Unable to send message: " + result.getException());
                    }
                });
        });
    }
}
```

I based my code with the quickstart: https://quarkus.io/guides/websockets
When the server client is just one or few the performance is okay, the *websocket send time* is 1-5 ms, which is alright. However when I set-up 20-25 clients performance starts to deteriorate. It fluctuates from fast to slow, and the streaming of video bytes gets delayed:

```
Total send time: 1 milliseconds.
Total send time: 0 milliseconds.
Total send time: 3 milliseconds.
Total send time: 95 milliseconds.
Total send time: 1 milliseconds.
Total send time: 6285 milliseconds.
Total send time: 6162 milliseconds.
Total send time: 207 milliseconds.
Total send time: 412 milliseconds.
Total send time: 8143 milliseconds.
Total send time: 6747 milliseconds.
Total send time: 5561 milliseconds.
Total send time: 5472 milliseconds.
Total send time: 5358 milliseconds.
Total send time: 5257 milliseconds.
Total send time: 5093 milliseconds.
Total send time: 4963 milliseconds.
Total send time: 4845 milliseconds.
Total send time: 6357 milliseconds.
Total send time: 488 milliseconds.
Total send time: 7491 milliseconds.
Total send time: 7462 milliseconds.
Total send time: 528 milliseconds.
Total send time: 6299 milliseconds.
Total send time: 4752 milliseconds.
Total send time: 4671 milliseconds.
Total send time: 554 milliseconds.
Total send time: 6730 milliseconds.
Total send time: 8051 milliseconds.
Total send time: 428 milliseconds.
Total send time: 129 milliseconds.
Total send time: 6042 milliseconds.
Total send time: 5949 milliseconds.
Total send time: 5855 milliseconds.
Total send time: 5753 milliseconds.
Total send time: 1 milliseconds.
Total send time: 1 milliseconds.
Total send time: 1 milliseconds.
Total send time: 1 milliseconds.
Total send time: 1 milliseconds.
Total send time: 5 milliseconds
```

And the longer the server runs with that number of connections the more delay it gets:

```
Total send time: 391493 milliseconds.
Total send time: 391290 milliseconds.
Total send time: 391186 milliseconds.
Total send time: 391054 milliseconds.
Total send time: 390932 milliseconds.
```

What could be the best solution for this? When for just 20-25 concurrent clients it is already under-performing (*not to mention that my target is 500-1000 concurrent connections per server*) and BTW the server it runs is Intel Core-i7 with ~3.5 GHz CPU with 16 GB RAM, I think this should be more than enough to handle 25 connections but somehow it can't.

Comment: There are two parties involved though; the server and the client. How fast data transfers depends on both. Surely the server is fast enough to handle thousands of concurrent datastreams but if the clients have full bellies then no amount of shoving a spoon into their mouths is going to make them eat faster. You want solutions? You first need to figure out what the problem is. Fluctuating performance is a symptom, it is not the causing problem.

Comment: Actually, I am thinking now of non-blocking Reactive Websockets implementation...

Comment: I may come from the client not consuming the data, and such block the writing. Can you check that your client is fast enough?

Comment: @clement Yes, it's fast enough. Also I think the issue here is the server not being async or non-blocking I/O rather than a client issue.

Comment: Also, I tested multiple clients, each separate browsers and tabs, that should be isolated enough, also other computer in the network to test that connects to the websocket. The playback of a web client with just one player (which if fast when it is the sole client) is affected when more clients connects, also I can see from server logs that the console output is getting delayed so it seems server is "choking"

Comment: I just tried with 2000 clients without trouble, can you provide a reproducer?

Comment: @Clement you mean 2000 clients receiving `ByteBuffer` or just text?

Comment: @Clement here's a demo app that reproduces the issue: https://github.com/questionaut/quarkus-websockets-streamer

Comment: Thanks for the reproducer! It's great (nice app BTW!). So, I tried it and I've seen the TCP buffers from the browser gets full very quickly which impact the dispatching. That does not mean there is no issue in Quarkus, and we should investigate. Can you (diy you) open an issue and if so can you add a link to your reproducer?

Comment: @Clement yes I did submit an issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/8859